# How to find first and last sections of an alphabetically sorted list in R

Tags: r, sorting, tail, head

how would I go about sorting a vector alphabetically and then getting the first 10 names and last 10 names printed according to the new alphabetical order?

i know to use sort(names) to get the vector in alphabetical order, and i know to use tail(names,10) and head(names,10) to get the first and last names but how to I combine these functions?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Using a small custom function you could do:

```r
ht_sort <- function(x, n) {
  x <- sort(x)
  c(head(x, n), tail(x, n))
}

names <- rownames(mtcars)

ht_sort(names, 10)
#>  [1] "AMC Javelin"        "Cadillac Fleetwood" "Camaro Z28"        
#>  [4] "Chrysler Imperial"  "Datsun 710"         "Dodge Challenger"  
#>  [7] "Duster 360"         "Ferrari Dino"       "Fiat 128"          
#> [10] "Fiat X1-9"          "Merc 280C"          "Merc 450SE"        
#> [13] "Merc 450SL"         "Merc 450SLC"        "Pontiac Firebird"  
#> [16] "Porsche 914-2"      "Toyota Corolla"     "Toyota Corona"     
#> [19] "Valiant"            "Volvo 142E"
```

Answer (score 1):

In one go, you could do:

```r
sort(x)[c(1:10, (length(x)-10):length(x))]
```

Or with `sequence`:

```r
sort(x)[sequence(c(10, 10), c(1, length(x) - 10 + 1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @stefan's answer, if you are not familiarized with functions yet, you might find this useful.

Let's say you have a vector `vec`. You can first sort and then combine the `head` and `tail` of your vector with `c`. Note that 10 tells `head` and `tail` to show 10 elements instead of the default.

```
vec <- rownames(mtcars)

c(head(sort(vec),10), tail(sort(vec),10))
```

Comment: This is essentially @stefan's answer

Comment: You are right. I wanted the OP to know it could be done without using a function (it took me a bit to figure out how to use functions, at first). Originally I wanted to post this as a comment, but I'm not able to do so yet. I'll edit to refer to @stefan's answer, but if you believe it's useless/redundant, I might delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply create a function -

```
headtail <- function(x) { 
  y<-sort(x) 
  print(head(y))  
  print (tail(y)) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `headTail` from `psych`

```
library(psych)
c(headTail(sort(x), 5, ellipsis = FALSE))
```